# I want to return some value from ssh command execution

Tags: shell, unix

My ssh command:

```
ssh -l prdmover $newFtpHostname "u/prdmover/checkTriggerFilePresent.sh $newFtpFolderPath ${TriggerFileName[0]}"
```

checkTriggerFilePresent.sh code below:

```
#!/bin/ksh

triggerFileLocation=$1
triggerFileName=$2

echo "Inside checkTriggerFilePresnt script for product feed..."
if [ -f $triggerFileLocation$triggerFileName ]
then
  echo "Trigger File is there..."
  exit 0
else
  echo "No Trigger File is there..."
  exit 1  
fi
```

Depending on condition I am returning values to my main script..
But In every case it is returning 127 to my main script. But I want to return 0 or 1.

Please advise..

Comment: Are you sure the script is found in the *relative* path provided? If you provide a *full* path to the script (e.g. `/u/prdmover/checkTriggerFilePresent.sh` (note leading slash)) does it work then?

Comment: I am also not sure on leading slash. But i will remove that and try

Comment: I think that leading slash not causing the issue..

Comment: Remove? In the example you show in the question there is no leading slash, that's why I asked you to *add* it. Also, can you please provide (complete) actual output of the command?

Answer (score 0):

After doing

```
ssh -l prdmover $newFtpHostname "u/prdmover/checkTriggerFilePresent.sh $newFtpFolderPath ${TriggerFileName[0]}"
echo $?
```

i would expect in $? the return code of the ssh command, not the return code of the script.

I would try to grap the output of the script:

```
R=$(ssh -l prdmover $newFtpHostname "u/prdmover/checkTriggerFilePresent.sh $newFtpFolderPath ${TriggerFileName[0]}; echo \$?"| tail -1)
echo $R
```